# Java Selenium find all links from website?

Tags: java, selenium

I currently have a function that checks for all empty href links on a single page. How can I edit my function to go through every link on every page of my site?

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code (since i do not know how your page is formatted)

```
while(links.hasNext())
{
your function here;
}
```

That is how people would usually go about parsing an entire document, and since any page is just lines of code, you can also parse it. Or, if using something like selenium, this is coming from an Appium perspective, you can try to create a table that contains the pointer to your hrefs, then make a rows variable that actually is populated by them driver.findByClass; and then just run a for or while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Would try to fetch the links and would say if the link is invalid based on the response.

```
for(WebElement w : links){
    URLConnection = new URL(w.getAttribute("src")).openConnection();
    if (conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        Assert.assertTrue("The link is invalid", http.getResponseCode() < 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: By any change do you mean HttpURLConnection on the second line? Im getting errors with conn as well.

Comment: Hey, sorry, i missed out a line. Have edited. give it a try now